# Hibernate annotatons and JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, annotations

I unsuccessfully tried to find in which version of Hibernate was introduced annotations. Did that from 3.2 version?

I also want to know from which version Hibernate is compatible with JPA API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Historically both Hibernate Annotations and Hibernate EntityManager were versioned and released from Hibernate Core. As of Hibernate Core version 3.5. Eventually the documentation for all 3 will be consolidated as well.

From: http://www.hibernate.org/about/entitymanager

So it is kind of difficult to answer your question. For some period of time both annotations and JPA support were developed under a separate project - and merged to Hibernate core in 3.5.

Also compare JavaDocs for version [3.3](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/api/) and [3.5](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/) - the former that not contain the `org.hibernate.annotation` and `org.hibernate.ejb` packages.

Answer (score 0):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernate_%28Java%29#Application_programming_interface):

> Hibernate Annotations (merged into Hibernate Core/ORM since version
>   3.6) – metadata that governs the transformation of data between the object-oriented model and the relational database model according to
>   the JSR 317 Java Persistence API (JPA 2)

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz oops, I got it, it refers to the fact of merging `hibenate-annotation` module to `hibernate-core`